# Pyspark convert Json to DF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this file .json and I need, convert it in DF, the file is this:

```
{
  "id": "517379",
  "created_at": "2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
  "company": "1707",
  "invoice": [
    {
      "invoice_id": "4102",
      "date": "2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
      "id": "517379",
      "cantidad": "21992.47",
      "extra_data": {
        "column": "ASDFG",
        "credito": "Crédito"
      }
    }
```

I need in this way, like df.

```
id.    , created_at,           ,  company, invoice_id, date                  , id.     , cantidad, column, credito
517379 , 2020-11-16T04:25:03Z  ,     1707,       4102, 2020-11-16T04:25:03Z  , 517379  , 21992.47,  ASDFG, Crédito
```

Comment: Have you started to write some code? could you show us what you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

by default spark try to sparse each line as a json document, so if your file contains json objects across multiple line, you will have a dataframe with one column `_corrupt_record`. To solve this problem you need to set the reading option `multiline` to `true`.
`test.json`

```
[
   {
      "id":"517379",
      "created_at":"2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
      "company":"1707",
      "invoice":[
         {
            "invoice_id":"4102",
            "date":"2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
            "id":"517379",
            "cantidad":"21992.47",
            "extra_data":{
               "column":"ASDFG",
               "credito":"Crédito"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"1234",
      "created_at":"2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
      "company":"1707",
      "invoice":[
         {
            "invoice_id":"4102",
            "date":"2020-11-16T04:25:03Z",
            "id":"517379",
            "cantidad":"21992.47",
            "extra_data":{
               "column":"ASDFG",
               "credito":"Crédito"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

pyspark code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("test.json")

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- invoice: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cantidad: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- extra_data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- column: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- credito: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- invoice_id: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+-------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|company|          created_at|    id|             invoice|
+-------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|   1707|2020-11-16T04:25:03Z|517379|[{21992.47, 2020-...|
|   1707|2020-11-16T04:25:03Z|  1234|[{21992.47, 2020-...|
+-------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
```

if you know the schema, it’s better to provide it to reduce the processing time and parsing all the types as you want

```
from pyspark.sql import types as pyspark_types
from pyspark.sql import functions as pyspark_functions
schema = pyspark_types.StructType(fields=[
    pyspark_types.StructField("id", pyspark_types.StringType()),
    pyspark_types.StructField("created_at", pyspark_types.TimestampType()),
    pyspark_types.StructField("company", pyspark_types.StringType()),
    pyspark_types.StructField("invoice", pyspark_types.ArrayType(
        pyspark_types.StructType(fields=[
            pyspark_types.StructField("invoice_id", pyspark_types.StringType()),
            pyspark_types.StructField("date", pyspark_types.TimestampType()),
            pyspark_types.StructField("id", pyspark_types.StringType()),
            pyspark_types.StructField("cantidad", pyspark_types.StringType()),
            pyspark_types.StructField("extra_data", pyspark_types.StructType(fields=[
                pyspark_types.StructField("column", pyspark_types.StringType()),
                pyspark_types.StructField("credito", pyspark_types.StringType())
            ]))
        ])
    )),
])
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("test.json", schema=schema)

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- invoice: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- invoice_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cantidad: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- extra_data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- column: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- credito: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
|    id|         created_at|company|             invoice|
+------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
|517379|2020-11-16 04:25:03|   1707|[{4102, 2020-11-1...|
|  1234|2020-11-16 04:25:03|   1707|[{4102, 2020-11-1...|
+------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+

# To get completely denormalized dataframe

df = df.withColumn("invoice", pyspark_functions.explode_outer("invoice")) \
        .select("id", "company", "created_at", 
                "invoice.invoice_id", "invoice.date", "invoice.id", "invoice.cantidad",
                "invoice.extra_data.*")
```

in the second example, spark doesn’t try to detect the schema, while it’s provided, but it try to cast the variables to the types you provided (created_at and date in the second example are timestamps instead of string)